# Pygame: When player hits the right barrier and I press left, he reappears on the left side of the screen? Why?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to detect the bounds of the player based on two objects at the right and left of the screen. The code works fine on the left side, but if I hit the right border and try to move left, the character moves all the way to the left and gets stuck. Any idea why this is happening?

```
depressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if (184 < plx) and  (plx < 965):
    if depressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: plx -=1
    if depressed[pygame.K_a]: plx -=1
    if depressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: plx +=1
    if depressed[pygame.K_d]: plx +=1

if 184 == plx:
    if depressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: plx = plx
    if depressed[pygame.K_a]: plx = plx        
    if depressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: plx +=1
    if depressed[pygame.K_d]: plx +=1

if 965 == plx:
    if depressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: plx = -1
    if depressed[pygame.K_a]: plx = -1    
    if depressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: plx = 965
    if depressed[pygame.K_d]: plx = 965
```

Here is a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZERXDl4GP7_lKq5J7K8sowQ3zmp0YvA3/view?usp=sharing) of the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like

```
if 965 == plx:
    if depressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: plx = -1
    if depressed[pygame.K_a]: plx = -1    
    if depressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: plx = 965
    if depressed[pygame.K_d]: plx = 965
```

Should be

```
if 965 == plx:
    if depressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: plx -= 1
    if depressed[pygame.K_a]: plx -= 1    
    if depressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: plx = 965
    if depressed[pygame.K_d]: plx = 965
```

or else you are setting your position to -1 when you press left.